# Error: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name

Tags: django, gdal, proj, proj4js, terriajs

I have installed Terria JS and Cartoview. when i upload layers in Cartoview then they are uploaded but the following errors come:

> Error Message:  PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, type, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name, datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name

> Error Message:  PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name

> Error Message:  Cannot find coordinate operations from `' to` '>

I installed gdal error handler and then was successful to get these error messages. can anyone kindly tell why they are coming? I have also heard that these errors are due to PROJ library. Please have a look. Thanks!

Edit: This seems to be a configuration issue because the Database used is PostgreSQL and not SQLite which is shown in the error. Can anyone kindly tell how to configure it to postgres?